# Pull to refresh not working on ListView in Android Build with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am currently digging into Xamarin Studio and am creating a simple sample app with a list view. This should use "Pull to refresh". I already updated the Xamarin.Forms dependency to 2.1.0.6529 everywhere it is used - the corresponding `packages.config` contains the following lines:

```
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.1.1.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.1.0.6529" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
```

I double-checked that each part - the PCL one, the iOS one and the Android one - contains it.

My list view is defined in XAML like this:

```
        <ListView x:Name="SearchResults" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" Refreshing="OnRefreshing">
            <!-- ListView definition -->
        </ListView>
```

I implemented the `OnItemSelected` and `OnRefreshing` methods.

When I run the app in the IOS simulator, Pull to refresh works, but when I run it on Android, I get a `XamlParseException` with the message `No Property of name IsPullToRefreshEnabled found` at the line which says,

```
this.LoadFromXaml(typeof(SearchPage));
```

in my `SearchPage.xaml.g.cs`.

The Android project is set to build for the latest platform and minimum API level 15, and I am trying to run this on API level 19. To my understanding, this should work...

What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you verified that the Xamarin.Forms package reference in your _Android_ project was also updated? (not just the reference in your PCL project)

Comment: Yes, I verified this multiple times. The packages.config excerpt I posted is from the Android project indeed.

Comment: You are running it on 19, but what are you targeting it to? I ask because it works for my app, which is set for minimum 15 and target 23 (even though the device I am testing on is 19).

Comment: I now did a cleanup with `git clean -fdx` and things got worse - The Android app now says, `The type or namespace 'Xamarin' could not be found in the global namespace`. But maybe Acr.UserDialogs is the culprit because it won't let me update Acr.Support.

Comment: Turns out that ACR UserDialogs is really the one which is causing problems. It needs older versions of libraries for dependencies than the newese Xamarin.Forms wants. Gotta find an alternative for that, then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It was a dependency clash. What I did:

- Removed all dependencies from the Android project
- Added only Xamarin.Forms and its dependencies which pulled the versions it needed
- Searched in the `Add packages` for `Acr.UserDialogs version:*`
- Selected the newest version of the package which matches the dependencies
- Did the same with `Acr.UserDialogs.Android.AppCompat`
- Used the same dependencies in the other projects

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through this link ? this explains in detail 
[Xamarin Forum Link for Pull to refresh](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28313/guide-code-adding-pull-to-refresh-to-xamarin-forms-android-apps).

Comment: This describes how to do this manually, but since Xamarin.Forms 1.4, PullToRefresh is natively available.